# Hash map with custom equals and hash code functions

Tags: java, kotlin, hashmap

In Kotlin as in Java, in the normal course of events, `HashMap` uses the `equals` and `hashCode` methods provided by the key class.

Suppose the key class does not provide those methods (that is, just uses the defaults provided by `java.lang.Object`), whether because it was written by someone else who did not foresee the need, or because it needs to have reference semantics in some other context and value semantics in the current one.

Is it possible to create a hash map and supply equals and hash code functions on the fly, without modifying the key class?

(I would be happy with either a Kotlin-specific solution, or one defined in terms of the Java standard library.)

Comment: You could wrap the keys in a class of your own making, overriding equals and hashcode in that to behave correctly.

Comment: If I got your question right, you could use the [Strategy Design Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm) to dynamically change `hashCode` and `equals`.